# Handlebars countdown with data from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js, countdown

I've been looking for the way to solve this problem but I couldn't find any.
I have a list of scheduled tasks, I get some data from each one, doing an AJAX call and display it throught handlebars:

```
  function getScheduledTasks(URL_address){
  $.ajax({
    url: URL_address,
    success: function(data){
      var source = $("#scheduled-task").html();
      var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
      $('.scheduledBody').append(template(data));
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log('error', data);
    }
  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Type</th>
          <th scope="col">Next Execution</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class= "scheduledBody">
        <script id="scheduled-task" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            {{#each schedules}}
                <tr>
                    <th>{{name}}</th>
                    <td>{{type}}</td>
                    <td data-countdown="{{timeSs}}"></td>
                </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </script>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The thing is, I have the time in milliseconds in timeSs, I would like to process it with some javascript function and get the countdown working in the same "script tag".

I've seen that exist some jquery function that makes this easy, but I have the library blocked in my work network.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with ```get the countdown working in the same``` ? Are you using some 3rd party library to show this countdown, if yes - which one and do you know what unit it uses for showing the countdown ?

Comment: Its not clear exactly what you need. It seems to me like you'd like a countdown that works in seconds and right now it is in milliseconds?

Comment: I saw here a solution that works with milliseconds https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp so that's why timeSs ara milliseconds, but that doesn't matter at all cause It can be in seconds too if I need it. The point is that I need in some way that a java script function takes that value and turns it into a countdown that works.

Comment: Any sugestions?